# Why is /usr/local/ owned by root?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have read somewhere (not sure where) that `/usr/local/src` and `/usr/local/lib` are directories made for local source codes and libraries (for example for the projects which you are developing on this PC). If that is so, what is the logic for them to be owned by the super user?

Comment: Given an operating system designed for multiple users, _who else_ could own it by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> somewhere (not sure where)

Your source was not correct. Read the documentation (emphasis mine):

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html

> The original idea behind '/usr/local' was to have a separate ('local') '/usr' directory on every machine besides '/usr', which might be just mounted read-only from somewhere else. It copies the structure of '/usr'. These days, '/usr/local' is widely regarded as a good place in which to keep self-compiled or third-party programs. The /usr/local hierarchy is **for use by the system administrator** when installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not found in /usr. Locally installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather than /usr unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software in /usr.